# Edit App.Config name-value pairs from a separate tool

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, app-config

I am trying to create a simple tool for a service person to update a few entries in the App.Config of a different program. The App.Config file contains custom parameters used upon initialization of our program.

Since the App.Config contains many sensitive items a tool is needed to ensure only certain parameters are changed. Thus, the reason not to allow them to edit the App.Config directly.

My questions:

1. How can I access the name-value pairs from the config sections of an App.config from a separate program?
2. Which is better suited for the UI: Winforms or WPF? Are their controls that make it easy to add more entries in the future?
3. The tool should allow the user to set either a String, int, double or Boolean.

Here is the structure of the App.Config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="Settings">
      <section name="Section1" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler"/>
      <section name="Section2" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler"/>
      <section name="Section3" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler"/>
      <section name="Section4" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler"/>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <Settings>
    <Section1>
      <add key="NAME_STRING" value="Some String"/>
    </Section1>

    <Section2>
      <add key="NAME_INTEGER" value="10"/>
    </Section2>

    <Section3>
      <add key="NAME_DOUBLE" value="10.5"/>
    </Section3>

    <Section4>
      <add key="NAME_BOOLEAN" value="true"/>
    </Section4>
  </Settings>

  ... Omitted ...

</configuration>
```

In the program which uses the App.Config itself, I can easily change the values like so:

```
NameValueCollection nvc = (NameValueCollection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("Settings/Section1");
```

Is there a similar way to do this from a separate program after loading the App.Config?

Comment: Just a note:  your question 3 isn't actually a question.  Is there something you want to ask about setting those types of data?

Comment: Ah yes, good catch! Just that the UI control should afford to the data type if possible. If there is error control like setting double where there should be an integer it would cause an error.

Comment: Have you considered encrypting the sensitive sections? Then you could let the service person change the unencrypted parts. This [link](http://www.dotnetprofessional.com/blog/post/2008/03/03/Encrypt-sections-of-WebConfig-or-AppConfig.aspx) has more info.

Comment: Thanks for the link @DeanOC . I will note this for next time. Unfortunately, for now we cannot change the App.Config program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An answer to Question 1:  An app.config file is an XML file.  It might be easiest to load it as an XML document and modify that programmatically, followed by a save, than to use `System.Configuration` classes.

ETA:  I believe it can be done with `ConfigurationManager`.  Look at the [OpenMappedExeConfiguration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms134269.aspx) method.  There's a good example there.

Comment: Thanks Ann. I've updated the Q to show how we update the values using the `ConfigurationManager`. Is there a way to do this after loading the XML?

Comment: If you mean, "with XML technologies", yes, you can do it with LINQ for XML.  If you mean "with the ConfigurationManager", I'm not sure.  It is possible to use it to override a configuration file with another one, but I don't know if you can edit and save the configuration file on the fly.  Let me look up a few things.

Comment: If you can't find anything can you show a simple example how LINQ would work in this case. I am unfamiliar with LINQ. Thanks.

Comment: @RyanR  I've updated my answer to include a link to an example.

Comment: Great! That link is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You could treat the app.config file as a normal XML file.  Use either XDocument or XmlDocument to load the file.

Then use XPath or Linq to XML to find the name-value pairs.

As for Windows.Forms vs. WPF, its a design decision.  Both have good and bad points.

**[Update]**

If you still want to use System.Configuration, you can use the `ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration` to get access to the other program's app.config file.  This returns a `Configuration` object, which has a `GetSection` method.

Comment: I've updated the Q to show how we can update the values within the program itself. Is there a similar way to do this from an external program?

Comment: As both @Ann and I recommend, don't use `System.Configuration`.  Just treat it as a XML file.

Comment: Thanks Richard. Can you show a simple example how one could use XPath or LINQ?

Comment: Thanks for your help Richard but I think Ann posted the link a bit sooner. Thanks again!

Comment: Try googling "c# xpath" or "c# linq to xml"